# Python: TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm creating an object of a class(with `multiprocessing`) and adding it to a `Manager.dict()` so that I can delete the item from the dictionary inside the object (the item points to) when its work completes..

I tried the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

class My_class(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(My_class, self).__init__()
        print "Object", self, "created."

    def run(self):
        print "Object", self, "process started."


manager=Manager()
object_dict=manager.dict()

for x in range(2):
    object_dict[x]=My_class()
    object_dict[x].start()
```

But I got an error:

```
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed
for security reasons
```

For curiosity, I removed the multiprocessing part, and tried like:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
class My_class():
    def __init__(self):
        print "Object", self, "created."

manager=Manager()
object_dict=manager.dict()

for x in range(2):
    object_dict[x]=My_class()
```

and it's giving me no errors and displaying the addresses of two objects.

What's that error and how to make it go away?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this yourself? I think I may be having a similar problem.

Comment: @Sky I just avoided the error by not using the `manager.dict` and classes together. Couldn't solve it. Just check whether you can change your approach and avoid it.

Answer (score 34):

Here is a shorter way to replicate the effect you are seeing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import pickle

p = Process()
pickle.dumps(p._config['authkey'])
```

> TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed
>   for security reasons

What is actually happening here is the following: the `process._config['authkey']` is the [secret key](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-auth-keys) that the `Process` object gets assigned on creation. Although this key is nothing more but a sequence of bytes, Python uses a special subclass of `bytes` to represent it: `AuthenticationString`. This subclass differs from the usual `bytes` in only one aspect - it refuses to be pickled.

The rationale behind this choice is the following: the authkey is used for authenticating inter-process communication messages between parent and child processes (e.g. between the workers and the main process) and exposing it anywhere outside the initial process family could pose a security risk (because you could, in principle, impersonate a "parent process" for the worker and force it into executing arbitrary code). As pickling is the most common form of data transfer in Python, prohibiting it is a simple way of an unintended exposure of the authkey.

As you cannot pickle an `AuthenticationString`, you also cannot pickle instances of `Process` class or any of its subclasses (because all of them contain an authentication key in a field).

Now let us take a look at how it all relates to your code. You create a `Manager` object and attempt to set the values of its `dict`. The `Manager` actually runs in a separate process and whenever you assign any data to `manager.dict()`, Python needs to transfer this data to the `Manager's` own process. For that transfer to happen, the data is being pickled. But, as we know from the previous paragraphs, you cannot pickle `Process` objects and hence cannot keep them in a shared `dict` at all.

In short, you are free to use `manager.dict()` to share any objects, except those which cannot be pickled, such as the `Process` objects.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I was passing a process instance into a queue and it caused this error.

Answer (score 3):

**Note: the solution below is in Python3 aka print()**. The same issue exists in Python3 also.

Well, in your specific example, we can work around the problem by pickling the `AuthenticationString` inside the `_config` dict that's part of the `Process` object as a bytes buffer and then gracefully restoring it when unpickling as if nothing happened. Define the get and set state methods that are called for pickling ops as follows inside `My_class`:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
from multiprocessing.process import AuthenticationString

class My_class(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(My_class, self).__init__()
        print("Object", self, "created.")

    def run(self):
        print("Object", self, "process started.")

    def __getstate__(self):
        """called when pickling - this hack allows subprocesses to 
           be spawned without the AuthenticationString raising an error"""
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        conf = state['_config']
        if 'authkey' in conf: 
            #del conf['authkey']
            conf['authkey'] = bytes(conf['authkey'])
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        """for unpickling"""
        state['_config']['authkey'] = AuthenticationString(state['_config']['authkey'])
        self.__dict__.update(state)

if __name__ == '__main__': # had to add this
    manager=Manager()
    object_dict=manager.dict()
    for x in range(2):
        object_dict[x]=My_class()
        object_dict[x].start()
```

I get the following output from running the code:

```
Object <My_class(My_class-2, initial)> created.
Object <My_class(My_class-3, initial)> created.
Object <My_class(My_class-2, started)> process started.
Object <My_class(My_class-3, started)> process started.
```

Which appears to be the intended outcome, and if you put a `time.sleep()` call in to keep them alive a bit longer, you can see the two sub-processess running.

Alternatively, it doesn't seem to upset anything if you simply delete that `_config` `authkey` and then you don't even need to define a custom `__setstate__` method.

Also, note that I had to add in `__main__` - without it python complained about not having finished its bootstrapping before launching sub processes.

Finally, I just have to shrug my shoulders at this whole "security" thing. It pops up in all sorts of places (with the same type of work-around required) and doesn't provide any real security.