# How to run parallel processes with multiprocessing terminate one of them from another and then restart

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

```
I get error when running the code
```

> TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for
> security reasons

I am very new to this... You can add your own completely new solution/code to this similar to my code as long as you can meet the goals(for example no need to use arrays to store process ids for termination etc...), goals are:
1.Running multiple processes in parallel and then when certain condition is met in STATECHECK
2.Kill processes that are appended to a sepcific Array (in this case main_processes,normal_processes)
3.Then terminate them from another process(i attempt to do so from reset() inside statecheck())
4.Restart the same process(randomx) from statecheck

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

data_dict = {'y': 4,
             'h': 5,
             'j': 6,
             'o': 7,
             'p': 3,
             'b': 11}


def randomx(key):
    for i in range(0, 2, 1):
        print(key)
        time.sleep(data_dict[key])


def move():
    print("Starting move2obj")
    for i in range(0, 5, 1):
        print(i)

def statecheck(np, cp):
    print("statecheck started")
    reset(np, cp)
    time.sleep(10)
    randomx()
    time.sleep(20)


def run():
    for key in data_dict:
        key = Process(target=randomx, args=key)
        print(main_processes, key)
        main_processes.append(key)
        all_processes.append(key)
        key.start()

    process24 = multiprocessing.Process(target=move)
    process24.start()
    process11 = Process(target=statecheck, args=[normal_processes, main_processes])
    process11.start()

    normal_processes.append(str(process24))
    all_processes.append(str(process24))
    all_processes.append(str(process11))


def reset(normal_processes, main_processes, *args):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("killing normal :", normal_processes)
    for process in normal_processes:
        process.terminate()
        process.join()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("killing combat :", main_processes)
    for process in main_processes:
        process.terminate()
        process.join()


def processes():
    print(main_processes, normal_processes, all_processes)
    return normal_processes, main_processes, all_processes


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    normal_processes = manager.list()
    main_processes = manager.list()
    all_processes = manager.list()
    run()
```

Comment: Any reason why you have defined `mainx` as a class but never really use it as such by instantiating? Shouldn't `run` and `reset` be staticmethods? The reason you are getting this error is because multiprocessing does not allow you to share process objects with other processes

Comment: I fixed it. If it does not allow to share process objects with one another is there any workaround  to achieve my goals ?

Comment: I posted an answer to do that already, to share process objects

Comment: That is right! Maybe i wasn't clear enough I'm sorry but if you read my question i specifically say all the goals i am trying to achieve while you did answer to 33% of the question you did not answer it fully so i didn't mark it as answered. They do pass data between but do not meet other requirements

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. If your own sample code you provided meets whatever goal you had set for it, but only fails due to the error above, then you can use the answer below to create processes using `MyProcess` rather than `Process` class and your code will work. However, if you are looking for someone to create a completely new solution then you probably won't find much help at online forums.

Comment: I am not looking for someone to completely give new solution but I am open to complete rework of my code since. Yes I understand in example you provided it is very simple fix. Unfortunately doesn't solve my task as a whole.  Termination of tasks is impossible from within processes it seems and I do not know any workaround around that so I was hoping for someone perhaps knowledgeable enough to point me in the right direction or give me ideas. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler way, relevant to your code, to reproduce the error you are getting:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

def a():
    time.sleep(4)
    print('done')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    l = manager.list()

    b = Process(target=a)
    b.start()
    l.append(b)
    b.join()
```

**Output**

```
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons
```

The reason why this happens has been explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026025/16310741). In short, you are trying to pickle something which is explicitly meant *not* to be pickled. That does not mean it cannot be worked around, however. You just need to use [multiprocess](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/), and make the the `authkey` of the process picklable:

```
import time
from multiprocess import Manager, Process


class MyProcess(Process):

    def _prepare(self):
        self._config['authkey'] = bytes(self._config['authkey'])

    def start(self):
        self._prepare()
        return super().start()


def a():
    time.sleep(4)
    print('done')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    l = manager.list()

    b = MyProcess(target=a)
    b.start()
    l.append(b)
    b.join()
```

**Output**

```
done
```

So, for your code, instead of using the `Process` class, use the above `MyProcess` class to create picklable processes.

With that being said, unless you know what you are doing and are aware of the possible consequences, it's always better not to try and work around such "issues". They are there, by design, for a reason. So, instead of creating processes and adding them to a managed list (and then also passing that list to other processes), you should **only** join/terminate processes from the process that created them.

**Edit**

> Also how is data passed between processes? in your example you do not
> demonstrate any data transfer between processes ? if i for example
> write print(l) inside def a it returns error?

What do you mean by "demonstrate" data-transfer? Also, what you are doing will obviously raise an error since `a()` does not know what `l` is. You need to pass the managed list as an argument to `a` for that to work.

Now about **terminating processes from other processes**, it's possible, but I can't really think of a use-case for such a thing which couldn't be done using other efficient methods. In short, if you are thinking along these lines you probably need to re-evaluate your whole approach.

If you still want to however, you can do this by creating the processes in another process using managers, and passing those instead of the actual processes to other processes. You won't need `multiprocess` for this, and neither will you need to alter the `authkey` of the processes themselves. Example:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
from multiprocessing.managers import NamespaceProxy, BaseManager
import inspect



class ObjProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    """Returns a proxy instance for any user defined data-type. The proxy instance will have the namespace and
    functions of the data-type (except private/protected callables/attributes). Furthermore, the proxy will be
    pickable and can its state can be shared among different processes. """

    @classmethod
    def populate_obj_attributes(cls, real_cls):
        DISALLOWED = set(dir(cls))
        ALLOWED = ['__sizeof__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__le__', '__repr__', '__dict__', '__lt__',
                   '__gt__']
        DISALLOWED.add('__class__')
        new_dict = {}
        for (attr, value) in inspect.getmembers(real_cls, callable):
            if attr not in DISALLOWED or attr in ALLOWED:
                new_dict[attr] = cls._proxy_wrap(attr)
        return new_dict

    @staticmethod
    def _proxy_wrap(attr):
        """ This method creates function that calls the proxified object's method."""

        def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self._callmethod(attr, args, kwargs)

        return f

attributes = ObjProxy.populate_obj_attributes(Process)
ProcessProxy = type("ProcessProxy", (ObjProxy,), attributes)


def func1():
    time.sleep(7)
    print('done')

def func2(l):
    proc = l[0]
    proc.terminate()
    print('terminated')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = Manager()
    l = m.list()

    BaseManager.register('Process', Process, ProcessProxy, exposed=tuple(dir(ProcessProxy)))
    manager = BaseManager()
    manager.start()

    p1 = manager.Process(target=func1)
    p2 = manager.Process(target=func2, args=(l,))
    print(p1, p2)

    l.append(p1)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p2.join()
    p2.join()
```

**Output**

```
<Process name='Process-2:1' parent=115344 initial> <Process name='Process-2:2' parent=115344 initial>
terminated
```

Just use `manager.Process` instead of the `Process` class to create processes. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72817277/16310741) if you want more details as to how the manager and proxy above work.

Comment: I understand now why it happens. But the problems i encounter begin when i start PASSING DATA from one process to another and then also that NEW/OTHER PROCESS being able to access that data and then also using that data to start the same process again if needed. Which would be normal_processes and main_processes , which I use later on to terminate certain processes instantly from another process.1.Start multi processes2. Kill 1 when condition is met inside one of the multi proc 3.restart that process again from one of those processes when condition is met.Processes should loop until terminated

Comment: Also how is data passed between processes? in your example you do not demonstrate any data transfer between processes ? if i for example write print(l) inside def a it returns error?

Comment: @GgjusticeV check edit

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you very much! And about terminating process from another Can you give me a suggestion of a efficient way of doing that or point me in right direction on how you would possibly do this? I found kind of workaround by sharing variable between processes and using X variable as a switch and then using loop that keeps checking IF variable X gets changed to Y if it did it terminates/restarts from main process. Processes are looping in the background and IF certain condition is met they start/terminate[which is main goal of this whole thing].

Comment: the way you are doing it seems fine to me @GgjusticeV